# plot a series of binary arrays

Tags: python, plot, binary

I have a sequence of boolean arrays, as a function of some parameter, and I want to find a nice way to visualize it in python. any suggestions?
something like this can be fine:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should add some information about your sequence like the shape.

Comment: As I said, a sequence of binary arrays - [True, False,..,True,True]. 
Assume the arrays are parametrizied by some parameter t: 
array(t) = [boolean_function_1(t),boolean_function_2(t)...]

Comment: Is the following code represents correctly your data: `np.random.choice([False, True], (10, 20), p=(.2, .8))`?

Comment: aaa-----yes------aaaa

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.hlines` to display your binary array:

Create a custom function whose for each row, group by consecutive True/False values, keep only True values and set `y` (row), `xmin` (start of hlines) and `xmax` (end of hlines)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def get_hlines_params(a):
    """Returns y, xmin, xmax arrays for plt.hlines."""
    data = []
    for y, row in enumerate(a):
        for b, col in groupby(enumerate(row), key=itemgetter(1)):
            if b == True:  # draw only True values
                x = list(col)
                xmin = x[0][0]
                xmax = x[-1][0] + 1
                data.append((y, xmin, xmax))
    return zip(*data)
```

Now you can plot hlines:

```
# dummy data
t = np.random.choice([False, True], (10, 20), p=(.2, .8))

y, xmin, xmax = get_hlines_params(t)
plt.hlines(y, xmin, xmax, linewidth=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: binary arrays]